# How to determine even/odd line of a texture in GLSL ES

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I need to remove all odd lines from a texture - this is part of a simple deinterlacer.

In the following code sample, instead of getting the RGB from texture, I choose to output white colour for odd line and red colour for even line - so I can visually check if the result is what I expected.

_texcoord is passed in from vertex shader and has a range of [0, 1] for both x and y

```
uniform sampler2D sampler0; /* not used here because we directly output White or Red color */
varying highp vec2 _texcoord;
void main() {
    highp float height = 480.0; /* assume texture has height of 480 */
    highp float y = height * _texcoord.y;
    if (mod(y, 2.0) >= 1.0) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
    }
}
```

When render to screen, the output isn't expected. Vertically it's RRWWWRRWWW But I am really expecting RWRWRWRW (i.e. alternate between red and white color)

My code run on iOS and target to GLES 2.0 so it should be no different on Android with GLES 2.0

Question: Where did I do wrong?

EDIT

1. Yes the texture height is correct
2. I guess my question is: given a _texcoord.y, how to tell if it's referring to odd or even line of the texture.

Comment: Make sure that texture height is 480

Comment: Using a `sampler2D` isn't a good idea for what you're trying to do here. You need direct, integer-indexed texel access, not interpolated sampling.

Comment: How do I disable interpolated sampling and use integer-indexed texture access?  GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE is not available in GLES

Comment: IMHO that shader should work as intended. Are you sure the error could'nt be somewhere else?

Comment: Is your output rectangle (I'm assuming an rectangle here) also exactly 480px in height? Your shader looks OK to me.

Comment: Your code works for me on my desktop computer (OpenGL 3.2 / GLSL 4.20). Please make sure that the triangles you're drawing correctly range from (-1,-1) to (1,1) and the texture coordinates from (0,0) to (1,1).

Comment: I had the similar problem on one videocard. I'm not sure it wasn't my fault in somewhere else (and can't test now), but `if (mod(y, 2.0) > 0.9)` solved it for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
void main(void)
{
    vec2 p= vec2(floor(gl_FragCoord.x), floor(gl_FragCoord.y));
    if (mod(p.y, 2.0)==0.0)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(tex,uv).xyz ,1.0);
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0 ,1.0);
}
```